# Setting DefineConstants dynamically via MSBuild import

Tags: msbuild, preprocessor, csproj, vcxproj

I have an .msbuild import that defines a property group containing preprocessor definitions, among other things:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_CONSTANT_VALUE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is `<import>`ed into both csproj and vcxproj files.  At build time, the C# preprocessor appears not to have visibility of the defined constants.  However, an equivalent C++ preprocessor definition in the same file works correctly, and the constants are discovered:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ClCompile>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>$(PreProcessorDefinitions);MY_CONSTANT_VALUE</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  </ClCompile>
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Any ideas why this only works in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Default property group declaration doesn't cater about previously existed properties and defined like this:

```
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
```

So make sure you are importing your .msbuild file **at the end** of your .csproj.vbproj, not in the beginning.

If this doesn't help - can you provide a log of msbuild with diagnostic level of verbosity and post link here.

Comment: Thanks, I tried importing at the end of the csproj, but the constant was still undefined.  In the end I modified <DefineConstants> in each csproj to contain a new macro that is defined in the .msbuild import.  This is fine for now, as I only need the flexibility for pre-processor constants, but would be nice to be able to inherit entire blocks of XML in the same way as vcxproj files.